# Asynchronous EntityFramework operations

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I have been converting some code into async methods.
I have a unit of work/repository/service design pattern and my **Repository** looks like this:

```
public class Repository<T> : IDisposable, IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    private readonly DbSet<T> dbEntitySet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        this.context = context;
        this.dbEntitySet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll(params string[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = this.dbEntitySet;
        foreach (var include in includes)
            query = query.Include(include);

        return query;
    }

    public void Create(T model)
    {
        this.dbEntitySet.Add(model);
    }

    public void Update(T model)
    {
        this.context.Entry<T>(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Remove(T model)
    {
        this.context.Entry<T>(model).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In this class, I want to make my **GetAll** method asynchronous. I found an article that had this as a method:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync()
{
    return await this.dbEntitySet.ToListAsync();
}
```

this is all fine and dandy, but I need the **string[] includes** to be added before I return anything to the user. So I have decided that perhaps I should leave the **Repository** alone and focus on the service, so I have this method:

```
public IList<User> GetAllAsync(params string[] includes)
{
    return this.Repository.GetAll(includes).ToList();
}
```

which I have tried to change to this:

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetAllAsync(params string[] includes)
{
    return await this.Repository.GetAll(includes).ToListAsync();
}
```

but I get an error:

> > Error    1   'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220258(v=vs.113).aspx it's impossible to get that error if you are `using System.Data.Entity` and IF you are really using EF6. Check the dll version again to make sure.

Comment: I would suggest uninstalling/reinstalling EF6 NuGet package from all of your projects (if it's a multi-project thing).

Comment: I did this and I still get the same problem :(

Comment: I stand corrected; it has compiled :D

Comment: for my case, I have similar for AnyAsync() but I cannot resolve it with help of Visual Studio, upvote for link me to the solution and thanks @mostruash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @mostruash has pointed out, if I put the **using System.Data.Entity** into my class references, it compiles and works fine.